# Errorbars and markers - linewidth

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, errorbar

How to make markers linewidth=3 and errorbars linewith=1 as it is in the legend, please? `linewidth=1` in the errorbar does not work. Many thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  # for legend handle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rvs = [2, 4, 2, 4, 7]
sigma = [0.564, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4]
rv_telescopes = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']

d = {'rv_times': times, 'rv_rvs': rvs, 'rv_sigma': sigma, 'rv_telescopes': rv_telescopes}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
colors = {'A': '#008f00', 'B': '#e36500', 'C': 'red'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.errorbar(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], df['rv_sigma'], color='none', ecolor=df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors) ,linewidth=1)
ax.scatter(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], marker='_', linewidth=3, color=df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors), s=1000)

for rv_teles in np.unique(df['rv_telescopes']):
     color = colors[rv_teles]
     df1 = df[df['rv_telescopes'] == rv_teles]  # filter out rows corresponding to df['rv_telescopes']
     ax.errorbar(df1['rv_times'], df1['rv_rvs'], df1['rv_sigma'],
                 color=color, ls='', marker='_', ms=30, linewidth=3, label=rv_teles)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=1, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here is that you might have been plotting things twice with different linewidth values. This can be fixed by removing the section of the code where things are drawn the first time:

```
times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rvs = [2, 4, 2, 4, 7]
sigma = [0.564, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4]
rv_telescopes = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']

d = {'rv_times': times, 'rv_rvs': rvs, 'rv_sigma': sigma, 'rv_telescopes': rv_telescopes}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
colors = {'A': '#008f00', 'B': '#e36500', 'C': 'red'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

for rv_teles in np.unique(df['rv_telescopes']):
     color = colors[rv_teles]
     df1 = df[df['rv_telescopes'] == rv_teles]
     ax.errorbar(df1['rv_times'], df1['rv_rvs'], df1['rv_sigma'],
                 color=color, ls='', marker='_', ms=30, linewidth=3, label=rv_teles)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=1, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]